# Coding for several frames

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to actionscript 3, and I'm currently learning how to code in external actionscript files. I have encountered a problem while working with multiple frames in my timeline; i can't seem to understand how to access objects scattered throughout several frames by code.

Let's say i have 2 frames in my fla file. The first frame contains the Movieclip "Box", the second frame contains the Movieclip "Box2". When i enter the code: `trace(Box)` i will recivie the output [object Movieclip]. When i enter the code: `trace(Box2)` i will recivie the ouput [null].

How do i extend my code beyond the first frame in my fla file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually move the playhead ahead to the frame where the object exists. If Box2 is on frame 2, you do:

```
gotoAndStop(2);
trace(Box2);
```

It will then exist. In practice, what moving the playhead does is create and destroy objects depending on the frames those objects exist. For example, if Box doesn't exist in frame 2, trying to trace its reference will also output `null`.

I'd also say that having objects scattered across frames is a bad idea. It makes manipulating them difficult. Most times, creating and destroying objects dynamically (as needed) is a better way to control state. In most real-world scenarios, at least in well structured Flash applications/games, you will never use a MovieClip with several frames, unless you're dealing with some keyframe-based animation.